# What are the vertical-edge plates called?

Tags: equipment, language

I'm assuming asking this question is ok since questions about kitchen equipment and cutlery are permitted.

So far I've only found steel plates that have a vertical edge. **Do these vertical-edged plates have a specific name that I could search for**, to check if they are available as a microwavable plates?
[image]

Most plates are pretty flat, which causes food to annoyingly go off the edge and onto the table.
[image]

Comment: The top one doesn't look like a plate; it looks like one of those small trays they serve Thali on.

Comment: "*Pie plate*" seems to yield some results

Comment: @Tetsujin: The steel plates are available in many sizes, including 6 inch diameter. Thali itself means "plate", and is just a way of serving the food. We take the katori's from the thali and place them on the table before starting the meal. The steel plate is a full-fledged dinner plate.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Thank you. Although "pie plate" isn't the right type, your reply led me to "raised edge dinner plate" and "divided scoop dinner plate".

Comment: When I was young and learning ESL(English as second language) I was taught the flat one is a dish while the raised edge one is a plate. But here it says the compete opposite: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/whats-the-difference-between-the-words-plate-and-dish

Comment: @user3528438: I agree with the answer on english.stackexchange. Hence the name "dishwasher".

Comment: Except that soup is served in a [soup plate](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk01xORh2hOBHormlWA6xDmkf8LGPkQ:1589010458254&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=soup+plate), strictly speaking [a bowl with a very wide, flat rim]; though almost everybody calls it a dish. tbh, no-one has ever translated 'thali' for me before now. In the UK it's pretty much defined as 'a selection of various foods in small dishes, served on a tray'. The material is almost always steel for both. You eat it straight out of the dishes, still on the tray.

Comment: This is news to me. I'm a native speaker of American English and I've always considered "plate" and "dish" to be interchangeable. Soup is served in "soup bowls" around here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Duarte's help, I found the plates are:

- [Raised edge plate](https://www.google.com/search?q=raised%20edge%20plate&tbm=isch&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwj25f2zx6TpAhUC0jgGHVzdDQwQBXoECAEQJw&biw=1322&bih=675)
- The [divided scoop](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.caregiverproducts.com%2Fassets%2Fimages%2Fcbl110-melamine-partitioned-scoop-white-w.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.caregiverproducts.com%2Fdivided-scoop-dinner-plate.html&tbnid=ttG4Ff8K2ycr6M&vet=12ahUKEwiP4_TIxqTpAhWC-TgGHYsiC-cQMyglegQIARBI..i&docid=nTXGYN0cSWvOIM&w=450&h=300&q=raised%20edge%20dinnerware&hl=en&client=ubuntu&ved=2ahUKEwiP4_TIxqTpAhWC-TgGHYsiC-cQMyglegQIARBI) plates.
- Dignity plates.
- High sided plates.
- Hi Lo plates.
- Manoy plates.
- Inner lip plates.

There are also [lipped edge](https://www.google.com/search?q=lipped%20edge%20plates&client=ubuntu&hs=eSn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDnbb8x6TpAhXhzTgGHULQD18Q_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1337&bih=675) plates, but it doesn't always satisfy the requirement of food not going off the edge.

Comment: There are also ‘deep plates’ and ‘wide bowls’ that might serve the intended purpose.  Also ‘pasta bowl’.  They tend to have a more curved transition than what was pictured, though.